# How to control fractional active noise in fbm?

Tags: matlab, random

I'm implementing fractional Brownian motion (fBm) in Matlab using `wfbm(H,L)` function, but I want to have some more control over the `wfbm`. I want to have diffusion constant as a parameter in the function, to control the noise generated, how can I implement that ?

`FBM_particle = wfbm(H,L)`

where, `H = Hurst parameter` 
and `L = Length up to which motion is needed`

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: @plasmacel `wfbm()` is in-built function in MATLAB to generate `fbm` but there is no such parameter defined in the function definition to control noise genereated.